# How to install spell-check in emacs 27.1?

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

I got a new laptop and installed new emacs (27.1) for windows 10. Now, I am back to the battle to get the spell check working in emacs. I am kicking myself for not saving the path to victory last time. When I followed the https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell (more than 2 years old) I stuck with an error at the "make" command during the installation:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Any tip will be appreciated!

Comment: The github page only mentions GNU Linux and MacOS, not Windows. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117664/2561714) helps.

Comment: Actually on the github site there is a section "Compiling with Mingw64 and MSYS2" so I installed with the "pacman... " command. I was supposed to go back to the linux steps, but it didn't work. 

The site you pointed out has Hunspell 1.3.2, not the latest 1.7.0 but it works so I am happy with it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Use Cygwin version of hunspell, https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=hunspell&arch=x86_64

Comment: How? The listed doesn't seem to have one that can be downloaded directly.